# Lambda invocation through aws chatbot does not respect timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, slack, aws-chatbot

I have set my `lambda` timeout to 2 minutes (initially it was set to 15 seconds)

However after that change my `lambda` invocation via `aws` chatbot fails (the test process via the console with a prebaked event succeeds)

```
Your command couldn't be completed because it exceeded my max execution time of 15 seconds.
```

Is there a timeout set by the aws chatbot that overrides the one set by `lambda` ?

**edit**: I just discovered that the corresponding `lambda` is invoked and completes its task as expected. Could this be a slack issue?

Comment: Same issue here as well. Did you find any resolutions on this?

Comment: Nope, not yet...